# Can I customize the list of text messages that I can send when I slide to 'Text' instead of 'Answer' for an incoming call?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sms, customization

I love the ICS feature that allows you to select 'Text' instead of 'Answer' or 'Ignore' for incoming calls, but I would love to be able to set what the options are for outgoing texts. Is this possible?

I am running ICS on a Droid RAZR MAXX.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Go to Phone app

[image: Android dock icons]

2) Tap Overflow Menu (triple verticle dots) > Settings

[image: Phone app screen shot]

3) Tap Quick responses

[image: Settings menu]

Comment: Thanks! Just want to point out that it's a little different on my phone, although I couldn't have found it without your answer. On mine, I:
 - Went to the phone app
 - Went to settings
 - Quick responses

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Just want to point out that it's a little different from the accepted answer on my phone, although I couldn't have found it without the accepted answer.

On mine, I:

- Go to the phone app
- Went to settings
- Quick responses

Hope that helps.